# What is the recommended guideline or pattern for methods that can time out in .Net?

Tags: .net, timeout

[ServiceController.WaitForStatus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35st9aw1.aspx)(status, timeout) throws a TimeoutException if the operation doesn't complete.

[Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx)(timeout) on the other hand returns a boolean - true if the operation completes; else false.

Is there a recommendation going forward ?

[A MSDN Connect forum post](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/436389/why-does-servicecontroller-waitforstatus-throws-a-timeoutexception) that I found leans towards the TimeoutException approach. Can someone please confirm ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the [elusive recommendation MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bff9tk5%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

> A better approach is to use the
> TimeSpan  structure as the time-out
> type. TimeSpan  solves the problems
> with the integer time-outs mentioned
> above.
>
> In addition, it is recommended
> that **you throw an exception when a
> time-out expires instead of returning
> an error code**. Expiration of a
> time-out means that the operation
> could not complete successfully and
> therefore should be treated and
> handled as any other run-time error.
>
> In the case of an asynchronous
> operation with a time-out, the
> callback function should be called and
> an exception thrown when the results
> of the operation are first accessed.

Apparently you have to search with "time-out" while all the APIs use "timeout" as the name of the parameter.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends on the expected outcome. If some process is expected to timeout (e.g. waiting for user input), you make it a return code. If the timeout is likely the cause of an error (e.g. a network operation), you make it an exception. You could even have two versions: one that returns a value indicating whether it timed out and another that just throws an exception.